# Set session and view State in Client side and use the value in Server side in ASP.net 4.5 after page reloading

Tags: asp.net, session, client-side, server-side, viewstate

In Asp.Net Pages, I want  session or viewstate (or anything else) to retain the value after refreshing the page ? Is it possible?
and I want to set them in ClientSide using jQuery or javaScript.
I couldnt find any complete answer in the web

**Update:** 
one of the answers is like this :

this is the $.ajax call for setting a session

```
function setSession(dayrange, startDate, endDate) {
        var d = "{dayrange: '" + dayrange + "',startDate: '" + startDate + "',endDate:'" + endDate + " }";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "dateTimePicker.aspx/SetSession",
            data: d,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                //alert(msg.d);
                if (msg.d == "Success") {
                    alert("set ");
                    location.href = "dateTimePicker.aspx";
                }
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

and this is the code in server side:

```
  [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void SetSession(string dayrange, string startDate, string endDate)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["dayrange"] = dayrange;
        HttpContext.Current.Session["startDate"] = startDate;
        HttpContext.Current.Session["endDate"] = endDate;
    }
```

what's the problem with this code? because *it doesn't go to server_side method*( SetSession)

Comment: is name of your page Datetimepicker.aspx in which you are running this ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad : yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

Change your data like this

```
var d=JSON.stringify({dayrange:dayrange,startDate:startDate,endDate:endDate});
data:d
```

There is a format to pass data to ajax call. Name and value of parameter should be in single quotes like this `'dayrange':'dayrangeValue'` but if you stringify data like above you don't need to do this.

Comment: Thank you, but its not working . the session is still NULL after page refresh

Answer (score 0):

Slightly change the data as below,

```
data:"{'dayrange': '" + dayrange + "','startDate': '" + startDate + "','endDate':'" + endDate + "' }",
```